# Job interview in front of the client?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, clients

A company I am applying for as a software engineer said they would like to interview me in front of their client.

I have had many interviews before, but never one like this. What could it mean? Is there any specifics I need to worry about?

Both the company and the job look otherwise attractive.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to accept answers within the first 24 hours; it discourages others from answering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've seen this happen as the client.

In my situation, my company was looking for new external consultants to join a cross-functional team. The new person will be hired by the consulting company, but with the expectation of starting out in my team from the moment they start with the consulting company.

Since the member was recruited specifically for my company, it was customary for someone from my company to sit in during some of the interviews to make sure that the new person would have the right skills and attitude to be successful as a member of the team. Since the consulting company in this case would only hire the person if our company would accept them, both my company and the consulting company would get a "yes" or "no" vote and only if both were "yes" would the person continue to the next interview.

If you are in the same situation, expect the client to ask some questions as well. But effectively, consider them to be just another interviewer; they are trying to determine whether you are a good fit for the job just as everyone else at the table.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine that this means anything else than that the interview will be conducted by an employee of their client (next to an employee of the company itself), instead of only employee(s) of the company.

They might want to do this to get an idea of how you would interact with their clients. That can be done by just asking questions, but they might even act that there is an issue with this client and you need to solve it.

It could also be a gesture to this particular client ("we trust you so much that we give you some influence in who we recruit and who not").

Answer (score 2):

If the position is pretty much dedicated to doing work for the client, full-time, then it's not that unusual at all.

Instead of wasting the time of hiring someone they think would be great for the client, then possibly having the client reject them for some reason, this puts part of the onus on the client to accept the new hire, since they had direct input into selecting the individual.

I wouldn't say you'd do anything different. While your employer is acting as an intermediary, it's basically an interview for a job that will be done for the client.  The job, itself, won't be that different and the parameters of the interview will be the same.

The client company would merely remove themselves from the process once you move further along and get into the logistics of on-boarding with the employer who signs your paychecks, so you'd just be looking to stick to the technical nuts and bolts of the work for the client, and their work environment, and assume the contractor-related discussions will be handled separately, in a future meeting with just the actual employer, once the client agrees that you are the best thing since sliced bread.